# Javascript: InnerHtml dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

I want to replace the content of a div with the content of second one. I want to get the name of the second one dynamically over the alt tag of an image(works) and load the content of it (doesn't work)...

Does anyone know how the following code has to be changed to get the content of the div?

```
$img = $(this).find('img');
var NewDiv = $img.attr('alt'); 

document.all.old.innerHTML = document.all.NewDiv.innerHTML;
```

Comment: you are confuded i guess.. tell me what you want exactly

Comment: Whats `old` in `document.all.old.innerHTML` ???

Comment: Please include the relevant `HTML`

Comment: Why you using `document.all`? it's [non-standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages/Using_the_W3C_DOM). If you trying to get DOM element by name that already exist in document why not simply use [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) and instead of innerHTML [Node.replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild)?